# Python global variable not showing dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

Here is my code (Sorry indents are messed up).

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

inventory = []
book = {}

# find index
def find_index(inventory, isbn, title):
    if isbn in inventory.keys():
        quantity = int(raw_input("""Add quantity: """))

def add_book(inventory):
    print("""New Book successfully added""")
    book.clear()
    return inventory

def remove_book(inventory):
    isbn = raw_input("""Enter the ISBN:""")

def find_book(inventory):
    print("""
    Search Menu
    ===================

    1. Search by Title
    2. Search by ISBN""")
    answer = input("""Enter your selection: """)

    if answer == 1:
        title = raw_input(""" Enter the title: """)
    elif answer == 2:
        isbn = raw_input(""" Enter the ISBN: """)


def show_inventory(inventory):
    print("""
    Complete Inventory:
    ===================
    """)

# menu method
def menu():
    global inventory
    selection = True
    while selection:
        print("""
        Book Inventory Menu
        ===================

        1. Add a book
        2. Remove a book
        3. Find a book
        4. Show Complete Inventory
        5. Quit""")
        answer = int(input("""
        Enter your selection: """))

        if answer == 1:
            book['isbn'] = raw_input("""Enter the ISBN: """)
            book['title'] = raw_input("""Enter the title: """)
            book['authors'] = raw_input("""Enter the author(s): """)
            book['pubyear'] = raw_input("""Enter publication year: """)
            book['edition'] = raw_input("""Enter the edition: """)
            book['publisher'] = raw_input("""Enter the publisher: """)
            book['quantity'] = raw_input("""Enter quantity: """)
            inventory.append(book)
            print(inventory)
            add_book(inventory)
        elif answer == 2:
            remove_book(inventory)
        elif answer == 3:
            find_book(inventory)
        elif answer == 4:
            print(inventory)
        else:
            print("""Goodbye!""")
            exit()

menu()
```

Here is my output

```
    Book Inventory Menu
        ===================

        1. Add a book
        2. Remove a book
        3. Find a book
        4. Show Complete Inventory
        5. Quit

        Enter your selection: 1
Enter the ISBN: a
Enter the title: s
Enter the author(s): d
Enter publication year: f
Enter the edition: g
Enter the publisher: h
Enter quantity: j
[{'pubyear': 'f', 'isbn': 'a', 'publisher': 'h', 'title': 's', 'edition': 'g', 'authors': 'd', 'quantity': 'j'}]
New Book successfully added

        Book Inventory Menu
        ===================

        1. Add a book
        2. Remove a book
        3. Find a book
        4. Show Complete Inventory
        5. Quit

        Enter your selection: 1
Enter the ISBN: q
Enter the title: w
Enter the author(s): e
Enter publication year: r
Enter the edition: t
Enter the publisher: y
Enter quantity: u
[{'pubyear': 'r', 'isbn': 'q', 'publisher': 'y', 'title': 'w', 'edition': 't', 'authors': 'e', 'quantity': 'u'}, {'pubyear': 'r', 'isbn': 'q', 'publisher': 'y', 'title': 'w', 'edition': 't', 'authors': 'e', 'quantity': 'u'}]
New Book successfully added

        Book Inventory Menu
        ===================

        1. Add a book
        2. Remove a book
        3. Find a book
        4. Show Complete Inventory
        5. Quit

        Enter your selection: 4
[{}, {}]
```

When I am attempting to show complete inventory I am just getting two blank dictionaries in my list/array. I tried looping and I am still getting blank dicts. I am new to python and help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll likely get a better response if you change the code you see to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it may help you in figuring out the problem on your own as well. Take out the smallest portion of code that is causing issues and look at it closer. But for your question, it seems a bit weird that you're using a global `inventory` variable to do anything, especially when your functions are already taking an `inventory` parameter. Try taking out globals and just using function arguments to see what you end up with.

Comment: @danielu13 thank you for the reply. I have been trying all day to figure this out and I have been trying a lot of different things and still cannot get it to work. I am very new to python so I am still learning as I go.

Comment: `if isbn in inventory.keys():` should be `if isbn in inventory:` otherwise you're giving up the O(1) behavior of dictionary and transforming it into a linear search.

Comment: It's great that you're trying to learn! I would try writing the same code without the book logic to get a more minimal example. That will allow you to determine if your error is in your dictionary logic or your book logic. You can then use that to examine the issue further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit for the behavior you are experiencing is in the `book.clear()` line in the `add_book` function; however, the problem is deeper than that. 
Since `book` is a global variable, every time you append it to your `inventory` array, you are actually appending a reference to the same global `book` variable. Since you modify the global variable every time you add a new book, your inventory array will end up being dictionaries that all have the contents of the most recently added `book`. This is why both entries are the same in the second case. When you call `book.clear()`, you are clearing the entries from the `book`, which makes up all of the entries in your `inventory` array.

To fix this problem, don't make `book` a global variable. Instead, define a `book = {}` local variable after the `if answer == 1` line, and append that to your global array, while also removing the global declaration of `book`. It should look something like this:

```
if answer == 1:
        book = {}
        book['isbn'] = raw_input("""Enter the ISBN: """)
        #fill in remaining fields...
```

Comment: This may be a bit more subtle, but I think one of the bigger things going on here that you hint at is that a _reference_ to `book` is being stored in `inventory` rather than a value copy of `book`. So when `book.clear()` is called, any references to it (like the one in `inventory`) will also be cleared. If what was in `inventory` was a value copy of `book`, then `book.clear()` wouldn't affect the copy in `inventory`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your variable `book` gets cleared every time you add a book and call this function : `add_book(inventory)`. Just comment the line :

```
book.clear()
```

in your `add_book` function.